# Count select row in Excel

Tags: excel

- I have a large set of `Excel` rows and i have empty row in between .
- So i wanna count that empty rows as groups .
- put every group count above row then delete all empty rows .

ex.

- data row .
- data row .  i wanna count all empty row below.put on cell on that row (3)
- empty .
- empty .
- empty .
- data row.
- data row.
- data row.
- data row .   (2).
- empty row.
- empty row .
- data row .  (4)
- empty.
- empty.
- empty.
- empty.
- .
- .
- .
- .
- etc

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? To automate the deletion of rows you will need to use VBA. Would you consider using VBA for this?

Comment: Yes, i can now delete the empty rows . but the problem still on how can i count that empty row as i mentioned above .

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your data in column A of your spreadsheet (starting in cell A1) and you would like to count the empty spaces and delete the rows as follows:

```
      Col A    Col B                          Col A      Col B
1     AAA                                     AAA        2
2                                             BBB        1
3                                             CCC        0
4     BBB                                     DDD        2
5                          ---- Output --->   EEE
6     CCC
7     DDD
8
9
10    EEE
```

The following code will achieve that outcome:

```
Sub CountEmptyRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rw As Long, count As Integer

    lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    count = 0

    For rw = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(rw, 1)) Then //If cell is empty increment the count and delete the row
            count = count + 1
            Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            Cells(rw, 2) = count //Display emtpy row count and then reset counter
            count = 0
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```